# Place text in center of pie chart - Highcharts

Tags: svg, highcharts

I would like to place a title in the center of a pie/donut chart in HighCharts.

I don't see anything in the chart options that would directly enable this, so I'm thinking it requires using the Highcharts SVG renderer -- `chart.renderer.text('My Text', x, y)`.

I have that set up but I can't get the text to be centered inside the pie.  Percentages don't seem to be accepted for x and y values. Is there a programmatic way to get it centered inside the plot, and to survive container resizing?

**Update:** Setting x and y to 50% works fine to center a circle (using `renderer.circle(x, y, radius)`)—but not to center text (using `renderer.text(text, x, y)`).

See result here: http://jsfiddle.net/supertrue/e2qpa/

Comment: I don't understand why Highcharts doesn't support this case.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to take into account the location of the chart, so if you use the 'left' and 'top' attributes, you can add on half the width of the plot and subtract half the width of your text bounding box. This would yield the exact center:

```
text = chart.renderer.text("My Text").add();
textBBox = text.getBBox();
x = chart.plotLeft + (chart.plotWidth  * 0.5) - (textBBox.width  * 0.5);
y = chart.plotTop  + (chart.plotHeight * 0.5) - (textBBox.height * 0.5);
text.attr({x: x, y: y});
```

Apparently the bounding box will be 0s unless you add it first.

Correction:

```
y = chart.plotTop  + (chart.plotHeight * 0.5) + (textBBox.height * 0.25);
```

So, my original thought, and this seemed fine, was that the text would be aligned by the upper left, however it is done by the bottom left instead. Thus, instead of subtracting half the height, we actually need to add it. What confuses me, and something I don't understand yet, is that to get the center you add only 25% of the height rather then 50%. Note: This does not appear to work on IE 7 or 8.

### MAJOR UPDATE

http://jsfiddle.net/NVX3S/2/

<- Centered text that works in all browers

What this new update does is it adds a new element using jquery after the chart is done. This works in all browers that I have tested (including IE7, 8, 9, Firefox and Chrome).

```
var textX = chart.plotLeft + (chart.plotWidth  * 0.5);
var textY = chart.plotTop  + (chart.plotHeight * 0.5);

// The width and height need to be calculated properly, so I made it a span.
var span = '<span id="pieChartInfoText" style="position:absolute; text-align:center;">';
span += '<span style="font-size: 32px">Upper</span><br>';
span += '<span style="font-size: 16px">Lower</span>';
span += '</span>';

$("#addText").append(span);
span = $('#pieChartInfoText');
span.css('left', textX + (span.width() * -0.5));
span.css('top', textY + (span.height() * -0.5));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very informative—I didn't know about the plotWidth and plotHeight properties. Only thing is it doesn't readjust when resized. See http://jsfiddle.net/supertrue/tH8FY/ (Also for some reason, the placement looks off center.)  Is there some way to use groups or percentage-based positioning to get this to work?

Comment: So, looking further into it, apparently the bounding box will be 0s unless you add it first. I updated the example above. More unfortunately, I found how to center it on chrome, however this doesn't work on IE 7 or 8. I edited your example to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/NVX3S/

Comment: Works great, thanks. One small caveat, the height of the Title appears to throw off the vertical position just slightly (I measure 60px between top of span and the circle of the chart, and 80px at the bottom). Adding Title height (aprox 18px) to plotHeight seems to fix it `var textY = chart.plotTop  + ((chart.plotHeight + 18) * 0.5);` Now, how to get Title height dynamically? http://jsfiddle.net/64td8/

Comment: I was thinking that highcharts might be providing an option to do so.I was looking for a property in their API reference.

Comment: One of the most important lines of this answer (for me) was `What confuses me, and something I don't understand yet, is that to get the center you add only 25% of the height rather then 50%`

Comment: I did a pretty similar version of this earlier and forgot it. Now after having the problem again, I googled and got your solution. Nice. I needed this for Angular2 though so I did an Angular version of this.

Answer (score 56):

Use this code to center chart title vertically:

```
title: {
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    floating: true
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pDdcd/)

[image: Donut chart with title in the center]

### Edit

Since version 2.1 The floating property can be omitted as the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#title.verticalAlign) states it is implied by the presence of the verticalAlign property

*When a value is given, the title behaves as floating.*

Comment: I also added a little css to format it too: <style>.highcharts-title {font-size: 38px !important;}</style>

Comment: this should be the correct answer, also if you want both a title and center text, use the subtitle option for the center text

Comment: Excellent answer. When using it for a pie chart with an enabled legend at the bottom, I found that I had to also add y: -10.

Comment: Exellent !! Simplest solution. This should be the selected answer instead of johnstorm's

Comment: @LachlanMcD. any solution you found with a legend in chart?

Comment: any solution you found with legend and center title? @Maulikpatel

Comment: @Hiral Not yet.

Comment: Found solution for legend and centered title ? @Maulikpatel

Comment: @AllanJebaraj Still not any solution for a centered title.

Comment: this will not work in center once u have  showInLegend: true,

Comment: The title is centered in the image, but suddently it isn't in the JSFiddle. Does anyone know if Highchart's `title.verticalAlign` is actually broken? JSFiddle uses the latest version, which right now is 9.1.0.

Answer (score 11):

The best solution is to rely on series center, instead of `plotHeight` or `plotWidth`.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            //innerSize: '60%'
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            ['Firefox', 2262],
            ['IE7', 3800],
            ['IE6', 1000],
            ['Chrome', 1986]
            ]}]
},

function(chart) { // on complete
    var textX = chart.plotLeft + (chart.series[0].center[0]);
    var textY = chart.plotTop  + (chart.series[0].center[1]);

    var span = '<span id="pieChartInfoText" style="position:absolute; text-align:center;">';
    span += '<span style="font-size: 32px">Upper</span><br>';
    span += '<span style="font-size: 16px">Lower</span>';
    span += '</span>';

    $("#addText").append(span);
    span = $('#pieChartInfoText');
    span.css('left', textX + (span.width() * -0.5));
    span.css('top', textY + (span.height() * -0.5));
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4dL9S/

Comment: This is a really reliable solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following.

`title: {
    text : 'title to display in the middle'
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    y: 5
},`

Answer (score 1):

First, you may want to check the html in your fiddle. 
You had a **width** on your container of `500` instead of `500px`.

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>​
```

Second, this fiddle is a bit quick and dirty, but I think it accomplishes what you wanted?

http://jsfiddle.net/e2qpa/3/

Comment: I know I can position it manually, but what I'm looking for is a solution that will center it no matter the size of the container. I updated my fiddle to have a container without a fluid size—http://jsfiddle.net/supertrue/e2qpa/

Answer (score 0):

```
var newChart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

//Set No data text
var textX = newChart.plotLeft + (newChart.plotWidth * 0.5);
var textY = newChart.plotTop + (newChart.plotHeight * 0.3);
var textWidth = 500;
textX = textX - (textWidth / 2);

newChart.renderer.label('<div style="width: ' + textWidth + 'px; text-align: center"><span>Dati non disponibili per questa selezione</span></div>', textX, textY, null, null, null, true)
        .css({
            fontSize: '16px',
        }).add();
```

Comment: Please explain your code and how it solves the OP's question.  Read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Answer (score 0):

I found this works when there is a legend and you set the text you want in the centre of the chart as the title:

```
events: {
    load: function() {
        const titleHeight = this.title.getBBox().height;
        this.title.attr({
            y: this.plotHeight / 2 + titleHeight / 2,
        });
    },
    redraw: function() {
        const titleHeight = this.title.getBBox().height;
        this.title.attr({
            y: this.plotHeight / 2 + titleHeight / 2,
        });
    },
},
```