# Adding text to the center of a D3 Donut Graph

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhx4gkhg/)

I am trying to insert basically a label to the center of a donut graph using D3. I was able to work with an existing code I found and manipulate it so all the slices of the graph mesh in the middle to appear like there is a label there, but I think it'd be a better idea just to figure out how to make it a more permanent home in the center. I am very new to JS and D3.

Any help is grealty appreciated.

Thank you

This is currently the code that is falsifying a label being in the center.

```
svg.selectAll("text").data(pie(data)).enter()
.append("text")
.attr("class","label1")
.attr("transform", function(d) {
   var dist=radius-120;
   var winkel=(d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2;
   var x=dist*Math.sin(winkel)-4;
   var y=-dist*Math.cos(winkel)-4;

   return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
})
```

Comment: I would use a different library for charts, d3js would make you write more. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17293220/1197775. Note how objects already have properties to represent things that you are interested when working with graphs: `center`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can simplify your code quite a bit. Since you are already centering the pie chart:

```
var svg = d3.select("#svgContent").append("svg")
    .attr("width",width)
    .attr("height",height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate("+width/2+","+height/2+")");
```

You can just add the text as follows:

```
svg.append("text")
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .text("$" + totalValue);
```

Note that since you are only adding one `<text>`, you don't need to bind any data to it, and can pass `.text(...)` a value directly instead of a function.

Comment: Oooooh look at that! Thank you very much. Question is solved. If there is any other fluff in the code, let me know if you could!