# How to display the total of the series values for a donut chart in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm displaying a donut chart using Highcharts and in the middle I've currently got the title; 'Transactions' but below that, but still in the middle, I'm trying to show the total number of the series values which should be €8,173.99.

I thought the following code would work:

```
events: {
  load: function(event) {
    var total = 0; // get total of data
    for (var i = 0, len = this.series[0].yData.length; i < len; i++) {
      total += this.series[0].this.y[i];
    }
    var text = this.renderer.text(
        'Total: ' + total,
        this.plotLeft,
        this.plotTop - 20
      ).attr({
        zIndex: 5
      }).add()
  }
},
```

I see no errors but then again the total is not being displayed. What am I doing wrong?

You can see the JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/tobitobetoby/1fqvzpdn/3/

Comment: You can take ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/q/17286457/3898339

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `events` object should be placed inside `chart` object. As for the adding 'Total' info, I personally think that the better idea is to just set title on load event using `Chart.setTitle()` function. Take a look at the below example.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.setTitle

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/yt5pj3yf/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But have you noticed that the total is displayed as 8273.99 instead of 8173.99 (which is the correct total)? Do you know what's causing this miscalculation?

Comment: Is there a way to change the total displayed based on the click on legend?

Comment: Yes, you could perform adequate calculations on `legendItemClick` event (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick).

Comment: Great Work, but i need total value should be in round number, without decimal points. how to do it?

Comment: The easiest and fastest way is to use toFixed(0) on all values. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bwt40jm1/.