# How to add text verticaly and horizantaly centered inside highchart solid gauge

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I'm using highchart solid gauge, and can't figure out how can I add a text inside the chart itself. I added dataLabels but it does not being rendered on the chart.

Here is my [Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iam_nash/szq1Lm36/1/)

```
    series: [{           
        borderColor: "#00B0FF",
        data: [{
            color: "#00B0FF",
            radius: '75%',
            innerRadius: '75%',
            y: 85
        }],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<span style="font-size:2em; color: {point.color}; font-weight: bold">{point.y}%</span>'

        }
    }]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways, but a simple one is to use the something like the following:

```
title: {
    text: "TEST",
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    floating: true
  }
```

For other options that require more javascript/jQuery code, see this other question:

[Place text in center of pie chart - Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732205/place-text-in-center-of-pie-chart-highcharts)