# onclick display donut chart pieces' information in center

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I am trying to create a highchart for our status page, whenever a piece of the donut is clicked it detaches, but then it also needs to display whatever information it contains in a nice format in the center of the donut chart, however I cannot get it to work.

I've managed to create a click function that puts the data from the clicked piece into a span below the chart, but I know there's a better way of doing this.

```
            series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        $("#displayStats").text(this.name + this.y);
                        },
                    load: function() {
                    var chart = this,
                        rend = chart.renderer,
                        pie = chart.series[0],
                        left = chart.plotLeft + pie.center[0],
                        top = chart.plotTop + pie.center[1],
        text = rend.text("text", left, top).attr({ 'text-anchor':'middle'}).add();               
                          }
                    }
                }
             }
        },
```

Please check my fiddle below, thanks for reading

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Staehren/ucweax9h/)

Comment: I think this is what you are trying to do:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732205/place-text-in-center-of-pie-chart-highcharts

Comment: Partially, yes, I am trying to display the individual piece data whenever a piece is clicked, in the center of the donut chart, not just a title.

Comment: I know you already have an answer...have a look at this all the same:https://jsfiddle.net/grrakesh4769/ndb9sphz/1/

Comment: Nice example Rakesh :) Really like your text formatting

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński thanks...but I did use an external div...which is simply ugly!!

Comment: Thanks for your examples guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use chart.renderer for adding custom label in your chart on point click:

```
  addLabel = function(point) {
    $('.cLabel').remove();
    var text = point.name + ': ' + point.y,
      chart = point.series.chart,
      renderer = chart.renderer;
    chart.renderer.label(text, chart.chartWidth / 2, chart.chartHeight / 2).attr({
      'text-anchor': 'middle',
    }).addClass('cLabel').add();
  };
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: https://jsfiddle.net/ucweax9h/13/

Comment: Thanks for showing me, I was already using the renderer, however mine wasn't working.

Comment: I have an additional question, if you don't mind, I have been trying to get a count animation, seen in examples as such https://codepen.io/shivasurya/pen/FatiB on the numeral labels, I have a feeling this could be implemented fairly easy with your existing solution, however I haven't been succesful. Updated the fiddle in the original question.

Comment: Here you can see an example how you can achieve this count animation: https://jsfiddle.net/ucweax9h/18/

Comment: Grzegorz is there any way you can tell me how to make similiar countdown on the element above the one you already added countdown to? I've been trying to do so, but I can't target the specific child element. https://jsfiddle.net/Staehren/2t4L0d67/

Comment: You should be able o change your interval time https://jsfiddle.net/2t4L0d67/7/ additionally you are clearing wrong intervals, I have corrected it in my fiddle